# How to make it work in PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, joomla

I have this code and it works in PHP 5.2

```
if (realpath ( __FILE__ ) == realpath ( (isset ( $_SERVER ['PATH_TRANSLATED'] ) ? $_SERVER ['PATH_TRANSLATED'] : $_SERVER ['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED']) )) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo ( __FILE__ );
    trigger_error ( 'Direct call of file' . $path_parts ['basename'], E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

but in 5.3.3 i have error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED in /var/www/user/data/www/site/plugins/system/u24_je_plg_lytebox.php on line 16

How should it be changed?
Thanks!

Comment: You're likely triggering the same notice (**not** an error) in 5.2 but have different `error_reporting` settings on the two servers.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php has an explanation of the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PHP4 variable use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` or `dirname(__FILE__)` instead.